# adding dropdown to table cell

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am facing some issues in eclipse rcp for setting the dropdown for a particular cell.
My requrement is to set the dropdown in the first row of the table.  And that dropdown should be able to remove also.
One more thing that drop should be able to filter the contents in the table. So My question is that

1) Is it possible to add the dropdown only to the particular cell or row?
2) Can that filter act as a filter for the table?
3) How do I remove once I add the dropdown to the table cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is entirely possible. I suggest you start by reading [Building and delivering a table editor with SWT/JFace](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Table-viewer/table_viewer.html), this tutorial contains everything you need to know.

As a rough outline, you will need to make the first item in your content model different from your data items - it will store the filter values. Then setup editing support on your `TableViewerColumn`s something like (this is just a starter - this code will not work on its own):

```
tableViewerColumn.setEditingSupport(new EditingSupport(tableViewer)
{
    @Override
    protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
        if(object instanceof FilterDataObject) // your model object you are using to store the filter selections
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) 
    {               
        final ComboBoxCellEditor editor = new ComboBoxCellEditor(table, getPossibleFilterValues(), SWT.READ_ONLY);              
        ((CCombo)editor.getControl()).addModifyListener(new ModifyListener()
        {
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) 
            {
                IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection)m_tableViewer.getSelection();
                FilterDataObject filterValue = (FilterDataObject)sel.getFirstElement();
                // .. update the filter on your TableViewer
            }               
        });             
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getValue(Object element) 
    {
        if(object instanceof FilterDataObject) 
        {               
            // get the filter value
        }
        else
        {
            // get your data model's value for this column
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) 
    {
        if(object instanceof FilterDataObject) 
        {
            // update your FilterDataObject
        }
    }       
});
```

Comment: OK. thanks for your valuable information. But still I would like to know that, can we add and remove the dropdown only for one cell in a column or a particular row? Also I have seen this site suggested by you. There they are applying filters to all columns.

Comment: Yes, you create a TableViewColumn for each column in your table, so can can have completely different editing support for each column. Use the `canEdit` method to decide if the cell should show the drop down or not.

Comment: You know by accepting answers people will be more likely to help you in the future...

Comment: That article is *ancient*. Is it really still usable?